# Break point not being hit on controller but data from controller is returned

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, knockout.js

I am using knockout java-script and I have an api call to a controller , this same controller has a number of methods that all work fine 
however when I place a break point on one particular method it is never hits that break point . This is quite mind boggling because when I place a break point in my java-script I can see that there is data coming back from that particular method in the controller . Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this ?

this is my knockout

```
function FetchDeviceRows(dtvm, item) {
    $.when(getSecureData("/api/DeviceHierarchy?parentCostCentreId=" + item.assetInstanceId() + "&noChildren=" + item.noChildren() + "&orgLevel=" + item.orgLevel()))
    .done(function (rows) {
        InsertActualDeviceRows(dtvm, item, rows);
        RefreshWholeDevicePage(dtvm);
    });
}
```

this is my DeviceHierachy Controller method which is being accesed by my knockout . The break point here is not hit but when I put a break point on 
.done(function (rows) in my knockout it shows that it has returned data

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<DeviceHierarchyRow> Get(int parentAssetInstanceId, int noChildren, int orgLevel)
{
    var hierarchies = _deviceHierarchyRepository.GetDevices(parentAssetInstanceId, noChildren);
    return hierarchies.ToList().Select(h => new DeviceHierarchyRow(orgLevel + 1, 0, 0, "", "", h.noChildren, _pageSize, false));
}
```

Comment: Is the browser using a cached result?

Comment: I have cleared my cache so I dont think that is the issue

Comment: You're parameter in the javascript code doesn't match the parameter name in the api controller action. You're problably hitting another action in your controller. Place a breakpoint in every action and see which one it hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query string is invaild.
Since you have not set a default value for the parameter `parentAssetInstanceId` on your web api, which means it is a default parameter and since you are passing `parentCostCentreId` the api cannot find a value for `parentAssetInstanceId` and returns a 500 internal server error, you should see this in your js console. Unless you have another `get` method that then takes in `parentCostCentreId` in which case your break point is in the wrong place.

Comment: thanks for that you were very right , silly mistake on my part

Comment: @Zidane No problem, I have done it many times myself and learnt to always have your console open